# data not displayed when passed from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display data sent from Controller to view in Laravel 5.8 but when I do in my controller:

`return view('index', ['user'=> 'mark']`

and I try to display it in the view using:

`{{$user}}`

nothing is displayed, why and how to solve this please?

when I do `dd($user)` in view I get 'mark' but it is not displaying using previous method

I tried what is in Laravel 5.8 documentations

Comment: Write like this return view('index', ['user'=> 'mark']);

Comment: @amindevloper I did what you said but still not displaying

Comment: ohh sorry you have to use compact to pass data in view

Comment: share your `index.blade.php` file

Comment: like this `return view('index',compact('user'));`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

//controller

```
$data['user'] = 'mark';
    return view('index', $data);
```

//your view

```
{{ $user }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, put:

```
$user = 'mark';
return view('index', compact('user'));
```

In your view, you can now access the user through Blade templating:

{{ $user }}